# Function used to remove numbers with a repeating integer skips one entry and i dont know why

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, for-loop

This is my function:

```
def repeat(x,Y):
    A = list(str(x)) #makes a list, A, of each digit: 101 becomes ['1','0','1']
    A = map(int,A)  #converts each value of the new list to integers

    for i in range(0,10):  
        b = A.count(i) #counts how many times each digit is present
        if b>1:         #if there is repetition
            Y.remove(x)
```

This seems to be fine when run in idle for a single number, however when applied to a list using a for loop, the function misses one value.

```
B = []
for i in range(100,1000):   #needs to be a 3 digit number (100 until 999)
    if i%17 == 0:
        B.append(i)         #creates list of factors of 17
for j in B:                 #removes any values that have digits that occur more than once
    repeat(j,B)
```

This returns a list which includes the number 663. When the function is re-run in the new list, that value is removed. Also when it is applied to a different list, 3 digit numbers with 13 as a factor, the same occurs, one value with a repeating digit.

Its not a major inconvenience, just a really annoying one.

Comment: Why don't you try `set()` , What is your problem? expected input and output ?

Comment: You're modifying `B` while iterating over it, which is bound to cause trouble.

Comment: the problem is, when the function is applied, using a for-loop, to a list of values, one value which should have been removed remains. I'm relatively new to python, how would i implement the set function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

255 which comes immediately before 272 is removed but 272 gets skipped. Similarly, 663 is skipped as 646 directly before it is removed.

I suspect it could do with in-place modification of the array as @interjay says.

ETA: With debugging statements put in, you can see that the numbers that come immediately after numbers that were removed, are skipped over:

```
def repeat(x,Y):
    A = list(str(x)) #makes a list, A, of each digit: 101 becomes ['1','0','1']
    A = map(int,A)  #converts each value of the new list to integers
    print 'Proceessing', x
    for i in range(0,10):  
        b = A.count(i) #counts how many times each digit is present
        if b>1:         #if there is repetition
            print 'Removed', x
            Y.remove(x)


B = []
for i in range(100,1000):   #needs to be a 3 digit number (100 until 999)
    if i%17 == 0:
        B.append(i)         #creates list of factors of 17
print B

for j in B:                 #removes any values that have digits that occur more than once
    repeat(j,B)

print B
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, don't modify a list while iterating over it.  Also, Python provides `Counter` to count iterables, so you don't need to implement it yourself.  Finally, since you are repeatedly filtering an iterable, it is sensible to use `filter`.

```
import collections
def norepeats(x):
    counts = collections.Counter(str(x))
    return not any(ci > 1 for ci in counts.values())

threedigit = range(100,1000) 
b1 = filter(lambda x: 0==x%17, threedigit)
b2 = filter(norepeats, b1)

print b2  #the result you expected
```